# In SwiftUI, what happens when an actionsheet shows up?

Tags: ios, swiftui

The default accent color of the button, will automatically change to gray(disabled or un-touchable) when an actionsheet shows up. But with custom accent color, this will not happen.

So what caused this behaviour of the button with default accent color?

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: I also had the same problem with UIKIt. For those who are having this problem, the solution is to give the button-type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon (as I couldn't find one) there's no documentation for it.

But as we can all observe, I believe if you use `Color.accentColor` in any views, and when an `ActionSheet` comes up, all views will be enumerated and if such view has `Color.accentColor` for its any color-able property, that property will be toggled (changed to gray and back to accentColor).

For instance, a ZStack with `Color.accentColor`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It seems any changes to `Color.accentColor` will also 'prevent' this behaviour. That is only the default system accent color will behave like this.